# Find the number of users who made their first order in each country, each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which looked like:

```
user_dataset
+------+---------------+------------+
|userid| Register_time |    Country | 
+------+---------------+------------+
|    1 |  03/02/17     |      TW    |     
|    2 |  20/03/17     |      SG    |     
|    3 |  26/03/17     |      PH    |   
|    4 |  05/02/17     |      VN    | 
|    5 |  01/10/17     |      ID    | 
|    6 |  03/09/17     |      MY    |  
|   ...|  ........     |      ...   | 
+------+---------------+------------+

order_dataset
+--------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
|orderid | userid |    itemid  |  gmv   | order_time |
+--------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
|1030132 |  3     |  3366770   |  27,0  |  24/04/17  |   
|1030137 |  5     |  6130641   |  69,0  |  02/02/17  |     
|1030147 |  1     |  6770063   |  87,0  |  25/04/17  |    
|1030153 |  6     |  4193426   |  82,0  |  05/11/17  |   
|1030155 |  4     |  8825994   |  29,0  |  03/07/17  |   
|1030160 |  2     |  5660916   |  44,0  |  30/01/17  |   
|....... | ...    |      ...   |  ...   |     ...    |   
+--------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
```

I have been told to **Write a SQL statement to find the number of users who made their first order in each country, each day.**

I don't understand the question, can someone explain to me what the output looks like? I'm not asking the Queries but if someone willing to write it would be wonderful tho.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hint:  Aggregate the data to get the earliest date for each user.  Then join in the country and aggregate again.

Comment: Read it backwards. For each day, do find the users having the first order. Aggregate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join the table `user_dataset` to a query that returns from `order_dataset` the date of the 1st order of each `userid` and aggregate:

```
select u.country, o.order_time, count(*) counter
from user_dataset u inner join (
  select userid, min(order_time) order_time 
  from order_dataset
  group by userid
) o on o.userid = u.userid
group by u.country, o.order_time
```

If there is a case a user has placed 2 orders at the same day, then instead of `count(*)` use `count(distinct userid)`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT a.userid, a.purchase_time,c.country
FROM purchase_tab a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT userid, MIN(purchase_time) As first_occurence
    FROM purchase_tab
    GROUP BY userid) b
ON a.userid = b.userid AND a.purchase_time = b.first_occurence
INNER JOIN user_tabs c
ON a.userid=c.userid
ORDER BY a.userid
```

Comment: Consider adding more explanation instesd of just posting a block of code

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    country,
    order_time,
    COUNT(*)
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN( 
    SELECT 
        userid,
        MIN(order_time) AS min_date
    FROM order
    GROUP BY userid
) o
    ON u.userid = o.userid
LEFT JOIN order ot
    ON u.userid = ot.userid
WHERE order_time = min_date
GROUP BY country, order_time
ORDER BY country;
```